# ESP8266 - Arduino firmware : IP address ok, but router don't route anything

Tags: arduino, tcpclient, esp8266

I have a problem, i  execute this simple code - send an http request :

```
include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

//Router 1 - Livebox
const char* ssid     = "Livebox-9e38";
const char* password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

//Router 2 - Android phone
//const char* ssid     = "DARKSIDE";
//const char* password = "xxxxxxxxx";

// server address:
char server[] = "www.arduino.cc";
//IPAddress server(64,131,82,241);

WiFiClient client;

unsigned long lastConnectionTime = 0;            // last time you connected to the server, in milliseconds
const unsigned long postingInterval = 10L * 1000L; // delay between updates, in milliseconds

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}



void httpRequest() {
  // close any connection before send a new request.
  // This will free the socket on the WiFi shield
  client.stop();

  // if there's a successful connection:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connecting...");
    // send the HTTP PUT request:
    client.println("GET /latest.txt HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.arduino.cc");
    client.println("User-Agent: ArduinoWiFi/1.1");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    // note the time that the connection was made:
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
  } else {
    // if you couldn't make a connection:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there's incoming data from the net connection.
  // send it out the serial port.  This is for debugging
  // purposes only:
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }

  // if ten seconds have passed since your last connection,
  // then connect again and send data:
  if (millis() - lastConnectionTime > postingInterval) {
    httpRequest();
  }

}
```

When I am on the router 2  (a simple hotspot router on a android phone) the code works.
When I am on the router 1 (a livebox supply by my internet provider), i have an IP address, i can see the ESP in the router (it's a web interface) but i can't get any result form the request (and i can't ping the module). The router don't route anything.
Of course the router have access to internet and from a computer connect to the router in wifi with the Curl command, the request work.

Have you some idea for me ?

Comment: Is it possible that your code is trying to send data just before having a valid IP address?

Answer (score -1):

try with these changes:

```
client.println("GET /latest.txt")

client.println( HTTP/1.1");

client.println("Host: www.arduino.cc");

client.println("User-Agent: ArduinoWiFi/1.1");

client.println("Connection: close");

client.println();

client.println("{\"on\":true}");
```